# Get name of structure instance from within a function

Tags: c, struct

Assume we have a structure defined this way:

```c
typedef struct s_test
{
    int number;
    void (*func) (void);
} t_test;
```

And there a function `my_func` defined this way:

```c
void my_func(void)
{
    // Some code to get the name of the instance of the structure `t_test`, in this case `a`
}

int main()
{
    t_test a;

    a.number = 42;
    a.func = &my_func;
    return (0);
}
```

Is there a way to get the name of the instance of struct `t_test` from within the function `my_func`?

Comment: No, because that name doesn't exist at runtime

Comment: Why do you need it?  If you want to create instances you could look at a factory method (or one of the other creational patterns).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible but you can store the name inside the function.

```
typedef struct s_test
{
    const char *name;
    int number;
    void (*func) ();
} t_test;

#define MAKESTR(x)  t_test x = {.name = #x}

void my_func(t_test *s)
{
    printf("%s\n",  s -> name);
}

int main()
{
    MAKESTR(a);

    a.number = 42;
    a.func = &my_func;

    my_func(&a);
    return (0);
}
```